# Making a URL W3C valid AND work in Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, w3c-validation

I have a generic function that returns URLs. (It's a plugin function that returns URLs to resources [images, stylesheets] within a plugin).

I use GET parameters in those URLs.

If I want to use these URLs within a HTML page, to pass W3C validation, I need to mask ampersands as &amp;

```
/plugin.php?plugin=xyz&amp;resource=stylesheet&amp;....
```

but, if I want to use the URL as the "url" parameter for a AJAX call, the ampersand is not interpreted correctly, screwing up my calls.

**Can I do something get &amp; work in AJAX calls?**

I would very much like to avoid adding parameters to th URL generating function (intendedUse="ajax" or whatever) or manipulating the URL in Javascript, as this plugin model will be re-used many times (and possibly by many people) and I want it as simple as possible.

Comment: What do you mean without "manipulating the URL in Javascript"? By definition, AJAX involves manipulating URLs in Javascript. Unless you mean some kind of server-side munging?

Comment: No, I mean I would like to avoid having to filter &amp; from the URL before sending out the request, because it would mean that I can't use the URL directly. That would result in numerous annoying bugs in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're running into the problem of having one piece of your application cross multiple layers.  In this case it's the plugin.

A URL as specified by [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) states that a URL should use a `&` token to separate key/value pairs from one another.  However ampersand is a reserved token in HTML and therefore should be escaped into `&amp;`.  Since escaping the ampersands is an artifact of HTML, your plugin should probably not be escaping them directly.  Instead you should have a function or something that escapes a canonical URL so that it can be embedded in HTML markup.

Comment: All right. So I won't get around escaping it somewhere. I had feared so. However, escaping it on the HTML side makes it easier. Thanks for the RFC groundwork.

Answer (score 1):

The only place that this is likely to actually happen is if you are:

- Using XHTML
- Serving it as text/html
- Using inline `<script>`

This is not a happy combination, and the solution is [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_4).

> Use external scripts if your script
>   uses < or & or ]]> or --.

The XHTML media types note includes the same advice, but also [provides a workaround](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4) if you choose to ignore it.

Comment: Mmm, if I'm not massively mistaken, I am getting trouble from the validator for using unescaped "&"s in URLs in HTML 4.01 transitional. Am I remembering this wrong?

Comment: In HTML 4.x, script elements contain CDATA so any ampersands should **not** be escaped (and the validator won't complain about unescaped ampersands). In attributes values they **should** be escaped, but browsers handle them correctly.

Comment: (This is why it is a problem in XHTML as text/html. The browser uses the HTML rules (`&amp;` means `&amp;` in a script) while validators use XHTML rules (`&amp; means `&`). XHTML as text/html was a silly idea, intended only as a stop gap until XHTML support was common, and Microsoft never got around to supporting XHTML.

Comment: Thanks for the background info!

Answer (score 0):

When you have markup of the form:

```
<a href="?a=1&amp;b=2">
```

Then the value of the `href` attribute is `?a=1&b=2`. The `&amp;` is only an escape sequence in HTML/XML and doesn't affect the value of the attribute.  This is similar to:

```
<a href="&lt;&gt;">
```

Where the value of the attribute is `<>`.

If, instead, you have code of the form:

```
<script>
var s = "?a=1&b=2";
</script>
```

Then you can use a JavaScript function:

```
<script>
var amp = String.fromCharCode(38);
var s = "?a=1"+amp+"b=2";
</script>
```

This allows code that would otherwise only be valid HTML or only valid XHTML to be valid in both.  (See Dorwald's comments for more info.)

Comment: Yes, I am serving ampersands in &amp; form to satisfy the validator, the trouble is that when I issue an AJAX call, it doesn't seem to be interpreted properly (amp; becomes the start of the GET parameter). This of course shoots down my AJAX requests.

Comment: He's right. You only needs to use ampersand for printing. You don't want to put ampersands when doing the requests with ajax. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try returning JSON instead of just a string, that way your Javascript can read the URL value as an object, and you shouldn't have that issue.  Other than that, try simply HTML decoding the string, using something like:

```
function escapeHTML (str)
{
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   var text = document.createTextNode(str);
   div.appendChild(text);
   return div.innerHTML;
};
```

Obviously you'll want to make sure you remove any reference to DOM elements you might create (which I've not done here to simplify the example).

I use this technique in the AJAX sites I create at my work and have used it many times to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I am producing links using a central PHP function, so I will get there with less code by doing the escaping / unescaping there. I was just looking for a way to avoid having to do even that, as it's going to be a basic function for a framework.

Comment: No worries it's even easier in PHP - I thought the problem was with the Javascript AJAX request itself.